# Instagram media objects ids

Tags: python, api, instagram

I m trying to get Instagram all media ids but failed . I tried https://graph.facebook.com/xxxx/media?access_token=xxxx. but it returns only 25 media ids not all media ids.
Can any one help please

Thanks .

Comment: Please show the code that you're using

Comment: Successfully done. Thanks for asking .

Comment: @funie200 can u please tell me how can i get videos ids?

Comment: There is still no code in the question. I can't form an answer but maybe the limit on results per API call is set to 25.